# Does using Heines definition of functions limit turns the function into a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am puzzled about something:

Heines defenition of functions limit states that:

$\lim_{x \to a} f_x = L$ exists if and only if:

for any sequence $x_n \to a$, $x_n \neq a$

the following takes place: $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{x_n} = L$

I am confused about one detail, when I substitute $x$ with the sequence $x_n \to n$, does that necessarily turns $f(x_n)$ into a sequence?

It seems logically correct, it's an endless sequence of numbers indexed by $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for each possible sequence $x_n \to a$, you get a sequence of values $f(x_n)$ and that sequence always converges to $L$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, by definition